# jQuery onclick only if variable condition met

Tags: jquery, count, size, toggle

I have a button that when clicked, should only execute its code if the number of div that have the class of "like" is greater than 0. The problem is that even if this is true, the button still won't execute its code. Note that I have tried both .length and .size() to the same result.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
countlikes = $('[id^=post_].like').length;
likestatus = 1;
$('#show_likes').on('click', function() {
    if (countlikes >0) {
        likestatus++;

        $('[id^=post_].like').toggle();

        if (likestatus % 2 == 0) {
            $('#hidelikedbtn').removeClass('hidelikedimgoff').addClass('hidelikedimgon');
        } else {
            $('#hidelikedbtn').removeClass('hidelikedimgon').addClass('hidelikedimgoff');
        }

    return false;

    } else {
        return false;
    }
});
});
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't understand the overly fussy selector. You want to count divs with the class "like". $('div.like') should be fine. Are you really assigning the class "like" to divs OTHER than ones with an ID starting "post_"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the number of elements with "like" class varies after the page loads, the problem is that you currently assign a value to `countlikes` only once, *outside* your click handler, so every time the handler runs it will be using the original `countlikes` value and not a current count. Move the assignment inside the handler and it should work. (Though given the variable is only actually used in one place at the moment you don't really need it, you can just test `$('[id^=post_].like').length` directly in your if statement.)

Also your question says "greater than 1" and your code says "> 0", so even if it worked it wouldn't be doing what you describe.

Also, unrelated to your problem, the last `else` case is redundant: at the end of the `if` you return false, and in the else you return false, so why not just move the `return false;` outside the if and delete the else?

Comment: thanks for pointing out the inconsistency in my question. I've fixed it. I'll tinker a bit with what you've pointed out and let you know my findings.

Comment: moving the variable into the handler fixed the problem, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need a `var` in front of your 'countlike' variable.

Also, you'll need the same thing in front of your other variable.

Comment: True, but I was assuming the code presented is the relevant code, so I was going based off that. If it is global, than you are right, it won't matter.